How do I fix the dependency issue with kb2919355 when installing node.js?
I tried installing the v20.13.1 (LTS) version of Node.js for Windows running x64 and got this error in the PowerShell terminal that the installer opened:
WARNING: 'choco' was found at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe'.
WARNING: An existing Chocolatey installation was detected. Installation will not continue. 
This script will not overwrite existing installations. If there is no Chocolatey installation at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey', delete the folder and attempt the installation again.
Please use choco upgrade chocolatey to handle upgrades of Chocolatey itself.
If the existing installation is not functional or a prior installation did not complete, follow these steps:
- Backup the files at the path listed above so you can restore your previous installation if needed.
- Remove the existing installation manually.
- Rerun this installation script.
- Reinstall any packages previously installed, if needed (refer to the lib folder in the backup).
Once installation is completed, the backup folder is no longer needed and
can be deleted.
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Upgrading the following packages:
python;visualstudio2019-workload-vctools
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
python v3.12.3 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
visualstudio2019-workload-vctools is not installed. Installing...
[NuGet] One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in
the Chocolatey lib folder. All dependency constraints must be resolved to
add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message
may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current
package operation: 'python 3.12.3 constraint: python3 (= 3.12.3)'
Unable to resolve dependency 'kb2919355': Unable to find a version of
'kb2919355' that is compatible with 'dotnetfx 4.7.2.20180712 constraint:
kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)', 'KB2999226 1.0.20161023 constraint: kb2919355
(>= 1.0.20160915)', 'vcredist140 14.0.23026 constraint: kb2919355 (>=
1.0.20160915)', 'visualstudio2019buildtools 16.0.0 constraint: kb2919355
(>= 1.0.20160915)'.
Chocolatey upgraded 0/2 packages. 1 packages failed.
See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
Failures
- visualstudio2019-workload-vctools - Unable to resolve dependency
'kb2919355': Unable to find a version of 'kb2919355' that is compatible
with 'dotnetfx 4.7.2.20180712 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)',
'KB2999226 1.0.20161023 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)',
'vcredist140 14.0.23026 constraint: kb2919355 (>= 1.0.20160915)',
'visualstudio2019buildtools 16.0.0 constraint: kb2919355 (>=
1.0.20160915)'.

To install node.js, I went to https://nodejs.org/en/download and selected v20.13.1 (LTS), Windows, and x64 for the respective fields. Next, I went to my Downloads folder and doubled clicked on the downloaded Windows Installer, and clicked through, accepting the agreement, allowing installation in the default selected folder, selecting to download Node.js runtime, and checking off automatic installation of necessary tools. I get a dialog saying the Node.js wizard has been successfully installed and then a terminal opens. I clicked enter, then any key as prompted, and allowed Windows PowerShell to make changes as needed. Then the error above appeared. To fix this, I tried looking to see if the versions of the specified software was compatible with the version of kb2919355, but there was nothing in the release notes that helped. In addition, I tried installing kb2919355 and found out it was installed, and then I tried upgrading it, and it was already the latest version. Lastly, I tried using the installer to uninstall and reinstall it, but that did not change the result.

Did you try the initial suggestion, If there is no Chocolatey installation at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey', delete the folder and attempt the installation again. If you couldn't install, did you try the 4 step solution?

I faced the same issue. I had previously installed vc++ redist and visual studio build tools through separate installer for some reason. This was causing the conflict. Here is what I did

Go to remove programs > search c++ and uninstall any redistributions already installed.
search for "visual" and uninstall visual studio build tools 2019 (in my case)
uninstall node
remove chocolatey folders from 'C:\ProgramData'
download a fresh copy of msi installer of node v17.19.1
install node through the installer. Remember to tick the checkbox which asks to install additional tools and packages.
let the installer run. Might take some time to do everything depending on your environment so be patient.

Hope this helps someone.

Node 17 isn't supported anymore, and hasn't been for a whole year now. The maintenance LTS is 18, and the active LTS is 20.
